# C++ How to initialize a struct through no argument constructor

Tags: c++

Node is a **struct** which defined in a **class** List_set private.

```
struct List_set::Node
{
    element_t  str_l;
    link_t next_ptr ;
    static link_t* find(link_t* current, element_t string_t);
    Node();
};
List_set::List_set():link_(nullptr)
{}
List_set::Node::Node():next_ptr{0}
{}
```

I want to use a constructor to initialize the Node, however the compiler always report an error:

**no matching constructor for initialization of 'list_set::List_set::Node'**

Can you please help to figure it out?

The next is the definition of class List_set hope it can provide some reference.

```
class List_set
{
public:
    using element_t = std::string;
    List_set();
    List_set(std::initializer_list<element_t>);
    bool is_empty() const;
    size_t size() const;
    bool contains(const element_t&) const;
    void insert(element_t);
private:
    struct Node;
    using link_t = std::shared_ptr<Node>;
    link_t link_;
};
```

Comment: No error when compiling with `clang++ -std=c++11`.

Comment: Is your struct List_set::Node defined in .cpp? Are you trying to initialize a Node instance BEFORE or AFTER the struct List_set::Node definition?